# Can application sessions share F5 load balancer connections?

Tags: session, web-applications, load-balancing, connection, f5

I understand that two sessions cannot use a connection at the exact same time. But I had thought it was possible for multiple sessions to share the same connection or pipe, similar in principle to a threaded application, where processing of execution is time-sliced.

The reason I bring this up is I'm somewhat perplexed by how the F5 load balancer manages connections, in relation to application sessions. I have a web server which connects to the F5, which load balances 2 application servers:

Client (i.e. laptop) --> Web Server --> F5 Load balancer for app servers --> (app server 1, app server 2)

I was looking at the number of connections on the F5 load balancer the other day and it showed 7 connections to app server 1 and 3 connections to app server 2; 10 total connections. But the actual application had hundreds of sessions. How could this be? If there are 1000 sessions, let's say, that averages out to 1 connection per 100 sessions. Something doesn't add up here, I'm thinking.

Can and does the F5 load balancer distinguish between inbound connections and outbound connections? If so, how can I see both inbound and outbound connection?  I'm thinking that, perhaps, there are 10 inbound connections from the web server to the load balancer and 1000 outbound connections (because 1000 sessions) to the app servers.

I'm thinking it should be possible to queue or share multiple sessions per connections but maybe that's not how it works, particularly with load balancers. Any help making sense of all of this would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using the OneConnect feature, this is exactly what it's intended for.  The BIG-IP manages an internal session state for these connections and can reuse and maintain server-side sessions for multiple external connections.

Useful for potentailly bulky applications but can cause issues if you have internal applications that reuse unique keys for session state (Java is a good example).

[SOL7208 - Overview of the Oneconnect Profile](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/7000/200/sol7208.html)

Comment: Fascinating. Thank you for your insight. Yes, the application is Java-based. I don't manage the F5 but I'll have to find out if this OneConnect feature is enabled. I was also curious to observe the number of connections coming into the LB and also out of the LB to the backend servers. But if I read it right, those 10 connections were to the backend servers, which must mean the sessions are being grouped per connection.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I noticed this a lot when monitoring Outlook Web Access and/or ActiveSync.  I could have 20k connections on the front end and 1k on the back end (not exact).

Where this could become an issue is if the application recycled java id's for sessions so you could have two people accidentally logged on to the same application session.

This is usually the behavior of accidentally caching Java session IDs and reusing those, but when building OneConnect profiles, these features can slip right in.

Comment: I was able to confirm that the F5 LB had OneConnect disabled. But it seems pretty concrete that the application sessions are sharing connections.

Comment: BIG-IP could be reusing idle connections which doesn't require oneconnect, or it could be using SSL session caching to lower transaction decrypt overhead.  There are a lot of scenarios where BIG-IP will reuse connections (instead of sessions for OneConnect, which would be also reusing a ton of connections)

The key difference is connections versus sessions.  BIG-IP can cache objects (if the profile was configured to do so) so that could account for a large amount of GET requests responded to without ever hitting the source server.  It all depends how the virtual server in BIG-IP's configured